# How do I select an interpreter?

Tags: pycharm

How on Earth do I choose an interpreter when setting up my IDE?

I have been learning Python for a month and understand the very basics.

I saved all my code to Github so I could reinstall PyCharm and start fresh (I have no clue what was going on behind the scenes, my computer was a mess).

Upon reinstalling, I realized I have NO IDEA how interpreters work. I understand what they do, but I am being asked to select a "base interpreter" and that confuses me.

I can click on random files and choose them to be interpreters... but I don't understand why a random file is accepted.

There is some obvious piece of information that I am missing. I can't even Google it because everybody seems to understand how interpreters work.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the interpreter as the run-time environment for your Python project.  For example, if you select the System interpreter you will need to select your local Python 2.X or 3.X install.  However, if you were to select Docker, you could use a specific version of Python to interpret your code.  This is very useful if you want to target specific versions or environments of Python.

You can find more about how to configure this in PyCharm per it's [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html).